# How do you run doctests from pybuilder?

Tags: python, doctest, pybuilder

There are examples for unittests in the docs and much of this is already integrated into pybuilder.

How do you run doctests in a target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I am just running a unittest for every module I want to doctest. There are 2 similar ways to do it. I have put this unittest into the pybuilder unittest directory in a file named `gmprod_tests.py`:

1) Without exceptions, just asserting the number of doctest failures to be zero:

```
import unittest
import doctest2 as doctest #pip install doctest2

class GmProdTest (unittest.TestCase):

  def test_docstrings(self):
    import bin.lib.gmprod
    (num_failures, num_attempts) = doctest.testmod(bin.lib.gmprod)
    self.assertEquals(num_failures,0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The advantage is that the output of failed doctests appears in your console output when you run `pyb`.

2) There is another way using exceptions. It is the same code, only the `test_docstrings` method now looks like this:

```
def test_docstrings(self):
  import bin.lib.gmprod
  doctest.testmod(bin.lib.gmprod,raise_on_error=True)
```

This way there is no detailed doctest error description on the console, but you write less code in the unittest :)